What is the simplest way to show that $f(z)$ is differentiable?
I am not very familiar with complex functions and I only use them from time to time. So, bear with me if I ask a not very smart question here...
I found somewhere the statement that:
$$ f(z)=\frac{z^2 + 1}{z}, \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\} $$
is clearly differentiable ($\equiv$ holomorphic) on its domain.
Maybe you will consider this as irrelevant (too simplistic function?), but I still asked myself a question about the best general method to demonstrate this.
Point $1$ - The first obvious point I noticed is that:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z} = 0, \qquad (no \,\, \overline z \,\, in \ f) $$
so that $f$ checks the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. (I am aware of the importance of these conditions...).
Point $2$ - But, all the same, and as far as I know, it seems to me that this is insufficient and that this function $f$ should first be put in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, so as to show that $u$ and $v$ admit continuous partial derivatives (on the domain):
Cauchy-Riemann + continuous partial derivatives => differentiable (is that right?).
So, I expanded $f(z)$ in:
$$ x \frac{x^2+y^2+1}{x^2+y^2}+iy \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+y^2} =u+iv $$
And this is where my question comes in:
Is this necessarily the way to go? Do we have to explicitely calculate $\partial u / \partial x$, $\partial u / \partial y$, $\partial v / \partial x$, $\partial v / \partial y$ to show the continuity of these derivatives, or is there a faster method?

Most of the rules you know from calculus work in complex analysis as well, so that for instance knowing that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable tells you that $fg$ is as well, and that $(fg)' = f'g + f g'$. (Addition, quotient, constant, and chain rules all work too.)
From these, and the differentiability of $f(z) = z$, you can see that all polynomials are differentiable as well. And then checking $f(z) = \frac{z^2 + 1}{z}$ becomes easy:
\begin{align}
f'(z) = \frac{2z \cdot z - (z^2 + 1) \cdot 1}{z^2}
\end{align}
by the quotient rule. This is, of course, only valid where the denominator is nonzero, but that was already a constraint on the domain of $f$.
Other useful starting points:
All the trig functions are differentiable on their domains, with the expected derivatives, and so is $z \to exp(z)$.
"log" is a little more complicated, because you have to be very careful about defining its domain, a bit like square-root on the reals. Speaking of which...fractional powers also satisfy the usual differentiation rules, but you need to be careful about how they're defined (just like when you try to define fractional powers of negative real numbers).
But the short answer is "Once you know these basic facts, everything else is pretty much like calculus."

Well, this is effectively very simple! So, what you say is that one usually doesn't need to go through partial derivatives $\partial u / \partial x$ and so on (which can be tedious). It's enough to "look" at the form of the function... And, as a counter-example, I could say that $f(z) = \overline{z} / (z^2 + 1)$ is not C-differentiable, just from the fact that $\overline{z}$ is not C-differentiable, right?

For that last statement...I'm not so confident about saying "because these rules don't apply, the answer must be X". But You can say that $f(z) (z^2 + 1) = \bar{z}$, and if $f$ were differentiable, then the left hand side wou;d be differentiable, but that would make $\bar{z}$ differentiable, which is bad...so $f$ cannot be differentiable.

I'll take note of this way of doing things, it's very clever.
